# MySQL str_to_date() function fails with years starting on Monday

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7 the sentence below converts from a date string in the format yearweek + weekday like `'201801 Monday'` to a date using [str_to_date() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

The code is failing when the year starts on Monday (happens this year and also 2007 for example).

Running this code should give dates in the range 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07, but except for the Sunday everything is moved to the next week.

```
SELECT 
str_to_date('201801 Monday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Monday',
str_to_date('201801 Tuesday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Tuesday',
str_to_date('201801 Wednesday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Wednesday',
str_to_date('201801 Thursday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Thursday',
str_to_date('201801 Friday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Friday',
str_to_date('201801 Saturday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Saturday',
str_to_date('201801 Sunday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Sunday';
```

Output:

```
 Monday,        Tuesday,      Wednesday,    Thursday,    Friday,       Saturday,      Sunday
'2018-01-08', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-07'
```

The same code works for other non-starting on Monday years like 2017:

```
SELECT 
str_to_date('201701 Monday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Monday',
str_to_date('201701 Tuesday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Tuesday',
str_to_date('201701 Wednesday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Wednesday',
str_to_date('201701 Thursday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Thursday',
str_to_date('201701 Friday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Friday',
str_to_date('201701 Saturday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Saturday',
str_to_date('201701 Sunday', '%X%V %W') AS 'Sunday';
```

Output:

```
Monday,       Tuesday,      Wednesday,    Thursday,     Friday,       Saturday,      Sunday
'2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-01'
```

Trying to set the yearweek to 00 instead of 01 like `'201800 Monday'` breaks the query so this is not the solution.

Changing the value of [default_week_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format) system var to start on Monday have no effect:

```
SET default_week_format=3; -- Have tried with every other possible value
```

So I have found no way to get the first 6 days of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the lowercase %x and lowercase %v.

i.e. `str_to_date('201801 Monday', '%x%v %W') AS 'Monday',` will give you 2018-01-01

Click here for more [Params](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)